# jQuery autocomplete programmatically search and SELECT first choice (if any)

Tags: jquery-ui, triggers, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This should have been pretty straight-forward, but none of the solutions in StackOverflow doesn't seem to work for me...

Using jQuery 2.1.0, I've set up an autocomplete using an Ajax source, autoFocus: true, and a select: function (event, ui) { ... } to provide me with key/value pair combinations.

As soon as I start typing in the input field, I get the correct options as a DDL, which I can then select using the mouse.

However, I would now like to programmatically trigger the autocomplete search, and then SELECT the first option (if available).

I trigger the search like this:

```
Preparer.autocomplete('search', LoginName);
```

The available choices show up correctly, but I can't seem to be able to select the first one programmatically!

I tried calling .select(), I've tried triggering keypress 13 and 9 within the control, and even tried performing the actions within a setTimeout function to make sure that the dialog was rendered correctly!

I even tried setting the option { selectFirst: true }, but still nothing...

Is there something else I could try??

Comment: [`autoFocus:true`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus) should do this out of the box. Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Autofocus just highlights the option, but it doesn't actually trigger the selection function... The reason I would like the selection function to be triggered is because I use it to auto-populate some additional inputs based on the selected option's key value pair!

Comment: Well, you can trigger a click on the first menu item: `$("#autocomplete-id").data("ui-autocomplete").menu.element.children().first().click()` Are you sure want to do this, though? Triggering a select will also close the menu, which seems counterintuitive. It'd be better to intercept the data in `source` and trigger your custom callback there, and not bother with `select` at all

Comment: No this is exactly what I needed, thanks! Can you post your comment as an Answer so I can mark it as Correct?

Comment: Sure, will post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in the comment above:

You can trigger a click on the first menu item:

```
$("#autocomplete-id").data("ui-autocomplete").menu.element.c‌​hildren().first().cl‌​ick()
```

Keep in mind: Triggering a select will also close the menu, which seems counterintuitive. It'd be better to intercept the data in `source` and trigger your custom callback there, and not bother with `select` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Search

```
$('#autocomplete-id').data("uiAutocomplete").search($("#autocomplete-id").val());
```

& 
Select

```
var results = $("#autocomplete-id").data("ui-autocomplete").menu.element.c‌​hildren()
.first().cl‌​ick()
```